# How to find line number and file name of error

Tags: php

By default PHP logs few types of error in error_log file but I am using custom error function .Here is my code-

```
<?php set_error_handler("customError",E_ALL);
function customError($errno, $errstr)
{
 $e=$errno . ",". $errstr;  
 error_log($e);
 die( '<h4>An Error occurred.Don't worry just <a href="javascript:location.reload(true);">Refresh this Page</a>. </h4>');
}
```

I want to log the line number and script name in error log file .The above code only logs the error number and error str .How to log script name and line number of error using above code.

Comment: -1 [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your custom error function can capture the file and line as arguments:

```
function customError($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    $e=$errno . ",". $errstr . "," . $errfile . "," . $errline;
    ...
}
```

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php):

> A callback with the following siganture. NULL may be passed instead, to reset this handler to its default state.
>
> bool handler ( int $errno , string $errstr [, string $errfile [, int $errline [, array $errcontext ]]] )

Comment: Add a dot after $errstr in line 2.